# swift 4- Save the last data of a text field in a label so that they are displayed when the app is restarted

Tags: xcode, swift4

I have a problem, I want to create a small app in which data in a formula can be charged.

Currently the data from three ViewControllers and one PickerViewController will be given back to the first ViewController.
That works very well too.

Now I want that the data at the start not on "nil" set but have a certain value.
Thereafter, the data entered last should reappear when the app is restarted.

I would like to apologize for my english, it is not my preferred language ...

Here is a part of my code how I wrote it

Main ViewController:

```
import UIKit



class RecivingViewController: UIViewController, SendDataBack, SendDataBack2, SendDataBack3, SendDataBack4 {

@IBOutlet weak var recivingData: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var recivingData2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var recivingData3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var recivingData4: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func userData(data: String) {
    recivingData.text = data
}

func userData2(data: String) {
    recivingData2.text = data
}

func userData3(data: String) {
    recivingData3.text = data
}
func PickerData(data: String){
    recivingData4.text = data
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "view1" {
        let SendingVC: SendingViewController = segue.destination as! SendingViewController
        SendingVC.delegate = self 
    }

    if segue.identifier == "view2" {
        let SendingVC2: Sending2ViewController = segue.destination as! Sending2ViewController
        SendingVC2.delegate = self
    }

    if segue.identifier == "view3" {
        let SendingVC3: Sending3ViewController = segue.destination as! Sending3ViewController
        SendingVC3.delegate = self
    }

    if segue.identifier == "picker" {
        let SendingVC4: PickerViewController = segue.destination as! PickerViewController
        SendingVC4.delegate = self
    }


}
}
```

one of the other ViewControllers:

```
import UIKit

protocol SendDataBack {
    func userData(data: String)


  }

class SendingViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var DataTxt: UITextField!
var delegate: SendDataBack? = nil




@IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
    if delegate != nil {
        if DataTxt.text != nil {
            let data = DataTxt.text
            delegate?.userData(data: data!)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to see data after app is restarted you should use user defaults.
For saving data

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "data")
```

For loading data in your view controller, if it's first load, when data is nil

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "data")
```

Comment: You don't need `.synchronize()`. It's obsolete. It can even cause lags if the defaults domain is large. The documentation now explains that the system itself immediately saves the value without ever needing to manually synchronize.

Comment: As @Moritz says the documentation says to not use it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: I tried your code, but "newValue" does not work ... I'm a bit confused
I apologize, but I am an absolute beginner in swift

Comment: New value is the value that you will save in User Defaults, which will get displayed when the app will be reopened. Simply the date value.

Comment: ah ok, but it does not work, i have the number 25 entered as "new value". But with a new start of the app I see again the text of the label. I would like to see the last entered number. I am a little bit confused again.

Comment: When you load the view, you check if you have a value for the label, otherwise you load it from User Defaults as explained, and then you should give the label the value you loaded from User Defaults

Comment: ok, i made it, it works wonderfully with my text fields, the last data is saved and displayed again.

Many thanks for the help!

But why does not it work with a picker View?
The Picker View stores the data normally in a label which is transferred to the Main ViewController. There, the data is also displayed but not saved ....

Comment: Theoretically it should work, but I don't know what have you done there. Also if the answer solved your asked problem you should accept it. Also  about the picker view maybe you need to update the question

Comment: I have now changed the output of the PickerViews into a text field, now everything works wonderfully!

Thanks for your help...